https post request to Google Apps Script returns 400
The goal of my project is to send to a Google Sheets spreadsheet the following data:

a value from a MCP9808 temperature sensor;
a datetime string;
a board ID.

To achieve this the MPY script sends a https POST request to a Google Apps Script.
I already did these kind of things for other types of boards and other programming environments (Arduino and Circuitpython).
Hardware used:

a Pimoroni PicoPlus2 (RP2350) microcontroller;
a Pimroni RM2 (WiFi/BLE) module;
an Adafruit MCP9808 temperature sensor.

The PicoPlus2 is flashed with Micropython (MicroPython feature/psram-and-wifi, pico_plus2_rp2350 v0.0.10 on 2024-11-18; Pimoroni Pico Plus 2 (PSRAM + LTE + WiFi) with RP2350).
The data the PicoPlus2 sends is accepted and handled by the Google Apps Script.
The data is arriving in the spreadsheet.
A Logger info writes to a Logger spreadsheet.
The result is: "success", however
the response to the post request, that the MPY script receives is:
400 (bad request).
I googled for similar cases but did not found any. I created a discussion post in the discussion page of Micropython.org on Github however no reply sofar.
The Google Apps script has been deployed and set for access to anyone.
The apikey is limited for websites; with restrictions to spreadsheet where the data has to go; the Logger spreadsheet; https://script.google.com/home/projects/*; https://script.google.com/macros/*; https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets/*
Question: anyone who can tell me what could cause the 400 response?
The following is the micopython script:
# Send data to Google

    import network
    import requests
    import ujson
    from time import sleep
    import utime
    import ntptime
    from machine import Pin
    from rp2 import country
    from machine import I2C
    from mcp9808 import MCP9808
    from secrets import SSID, PASSWORD, GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT_URL, GOOGLE_API_KEY
    
    led = Pin(25, Pin.OUT)
    
    i2c = I2C(0, scl=machine.Pin(5), sda=machine.Pin(4))
    
    sensor = MCP9808(i2c)
    
    try_cnt = 0
    max_try_cnt = 10
    
    
    # connect to wifi
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF, pin_on=32, pin_out=35, pin_in=35, pin_wake=35, pin_clock=34, pin_cs=33)
    
    #rp2.country('PT')
    
    def ck_temp():
        tempC = 0.00
        tempF = 0.00
        
        try_cnt = 0
        try:
            tempC = sensor.get_temp()  # float
            tempF = (tempC * 9/5) + 32
            print("temp = {:7.4f} ºC, {:7.4f} ºF".format(tempC, tempF), end="\n\n")
        except OSError as e:
            if e.errno == 110:
                try_cnt += 1
                if try_cnt > max_try_cnt:
                    return
                time.sleep(2)
        return tempC
    
    def do_connect():
        wlan.active(True)
        try_cnt = 0
        try:
            wlan.connect(SSID, PASSWORD)
        except OSError as error:
            print(f'error is {error}')
    
        msg_shown = False
        while wlan.isconnected() is False:
            if not msg_shown:
                msg_shown = True
                print('Waiting for connection...')
            try_cnt += 1
            if try_cnt > 10:
                print(f"failed to connect WiFi 10 times. Going into endless loop")
                wlan.active(False)
                while True:
                    sleep(5)
            sleep(1)
        led.value(1)
        print("wlan connected to: \"{}\"".format(SSID), end="\n")
        print("IP address = \"{}\"".format(wlan.ifconfig()[0]), end="\n\n")
    
    def cleanup():
        if wlan.isconnected() == True:
            wlan.disconnect()
        led.value(0)
    
    
    def handle_request():
        yy = 0
        mo = 1
        dd = 2
        hh = 3
        mi = 4
        ss = 5
        ntp_time = ntptime.time()
    
        # Convert Unix time to a tuple representing the local time
        local_time = utime.localtime(ntp_time)  # GMT
    
        # Format the local time as a datetime string
        datetimeStr = "{:04d}-{:02d}-{:02d}T{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}Z".format(
            local_time[yy], local_time[mo], local_time[dd], 
            local_time[hh], local_time[mi], local_time[ss]
        )
    
        print("ntp_time = {}".format(datetimeStr), end='\n')
        
        tempc = ck_temp()
        print("tempc = {:f}".format(tempc), end='\n')
    
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        url = GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT_URL
        jsonPayload = ujson.dumps({'key':GOOGLE_API_KEY,'data':{'date':datetimeStr,'tempc':tempc,'id':'PicoPlus2'}})
        print("jsonPayload = {}".format(jsonPayload), end='\n')
        print("GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT_URL = {}".format(GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT_URL), end='\n')
        
        try:
            r = requests.post(url,data=jsonPayload,headers=headers)
            print("Response text = {}".format(r.text), end='\n')
            status_code = r.status_code
            print("request status_code = {}".format(status_code), end='\n')
            if status_code == 400:  # = Bad Request
                cleanup()
                raise RuntimeError
                
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f"error: {e}")
            cleanup()
            raise
            
    def main():
        while True:
            if wlan.isconnected() == False:
                do_connect()
            # Check again before sending data to Google
            if wlan.isconnected() == True:
                handle_request()
     
            sleep(10)
        
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()


Below the Google Apps Script:

    /*
    * Filename: Código.gs
    * Project: PicoPlus2_dtg (= PicoPlus2 data-to-Google)
    */
    function doPost(e) {
      try {
        //e = {date:"2024-11-19T17:58:52Z",tempC:24.3767,id:"PicoPlus2"};
      
        var my_debug = true;
    
        if (my_debug)
          Logger = BetterLog.useSpreadsheet('<BetterLog_spreadsheet_ID>'); // Sheet "Logger" (https://github.com/peterherrmann/BetterLog)
        // 2024-11-12: BetterLog installed here in Apps Script - Bibliotecas + ID '<Library_ID>'
        if (my_debug)
          Logger.log("e = %s", e);
    
        var params = e.postData.contents;
        if (my_debug)
          Logger.log("params= %s\n", params);
    
        var result = 'Ok'; // assume success
    
        if (params == undefined) {
          result = 'No Parameters';
        } else {
          var id = '<Spreadsheet_ID>';// Spreadsheet ID
        
          var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getActiveSheet();
          var newRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
          var rowData = [];
          
          // Parse the main JSON string 
          var jsonObj = JSON.parse(params);
          if (my_debug)
            Logger.log("jsonObj= %s\n", jsonObj);
    
          var dataObj = jsonObj.data;
          if (my_debug)
            Logger.log("dataObj= %s\n", dataObj);
    
          // Extract individual elements from data
          rowData[0] = dataObj.date;
    
          rowData[1] = dataObj.tempc;
    
          rowData[2] = dataObj.id;
    
          rowData.push(new Date()); // Add the datetime of execution of this macro
          if (my_debug)
            Logger.log("rowData = %s\n", JSON.stringify(rowData));
          // Write new row below
          var newRange = sheet.getRange(newRow, 1, 1, rowData.length);
          newRange.setValues([rowData]);
        }
    
        // Create result object
        var result = { 
          status: "success", 
          data: dataObj 
        };
    
        if (my_debug)
          Logger.log("result = %s\n", result);
    
        // Return result of operation
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
    
      } catch (error) {
        if (my_debug)
          Logger.log("Error: " + error.message);
        
        var errorResult = { 
          status: "error", 
          message: error.message
        };
    
        if (my_debug)
          Logger.log("error result = %s\n", result);
        
        // Return result of operation in error
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
      } 
    }



The question is clear and valid, but it could be further improved with some formatting enhancements to increase readability

Rephrased and formatted the text for better readability as suggested by rizzling. Thank  you for your advice rizzling!
